# Slidetoggle a div based on the link clicked

Tags: jquery

Trying to get the div with class sbox to slide up and down based on the stoggle that has been clicked. Can't figure this out. (I have hundreds of these so I'd like to set up something generic instead of multiple different classes.)

```
$(".stoggle").click(function () {
    $(this).slideToggle("fast");
});


<div class="wrapper">
    <a class="stoggle" href="#">Read Bio</a>
    <div class="sbox" style="display:none;">
        Cras porta orci blandit at magna.
    </div>
</div>

 <div class="wrapper">
    <a class="stoggle" href="#">Read Bio</a>
    <div class="sbox" style="display:none;">
        Lorem Ipsum
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give each a an id, like `a-1`.

Give each .sbox an id, like `a-1-div`.

In the click function:

```
$( '#' + $( this ).attr( 'id' ) + '-div' ).slideToggle("fast");
```

-- edit --
Try:

```
$( this ).next( '.sbox' ).slideToggle( 'fast' );
```

Comment: I need something more generic, possibly using the "this" statement.